# centering fontawesome component with faPlay icon inside a square and round button in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm using reactjs , react-bootstrap, bootstrap and fontawesome as dependencies.

I have a fontAwesome component inside a react-bootstrap button, that has `text-center` as a className, every other icon is centered the same way with no problems, except the faPlay icon which seems a bit off to the left.

I should add that the parent button is a square with a length of 2em.

here it is in [action](https://5cfbc87d36987400086fbb8b--pomoclock.netlify.com/).

here's the [module](https://github.com/soufyakoub/Pomodoro-Clock/blob/test/pomodoro-clock/src/controls.js) that contains that component in the repo.

the faPlay doesn't have some special kind of CSS or something like that,
so what's causing it not be centered but everything else is?

Answer (score 2):

Add Flexbox CSS property to center it

```
button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an optical `illusion`. It is currently centered `horizontally` and `vertically`.

Comment: i tried (on a paper) to use the same reasoning for centering text , right and left white spaces are equal , and that gives me a triangle that's not centered by its gravity center .  so i guess i should center it manually .

Comment: Please add `background: white;` to `svg` in fabPlay icon and check. :D

Comment: I cheked and its little bit like `1px` above from center

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution in scss . here's how it [looks](https://pomoclock.netlify.com/) . need some feedback please is it just an optical illusion or i'm i right ?

```
@function sqrt($r) {
    $x0: 1;
    $x1: $x0;

    @for $i from 1 through 10 {
        $x1: $x0 - ($x0 * $x0 - abs($r)) / (2 * $x0);
        $x0: $x1;
    }

    @return $x1;
}

.fa-play-circumcenter svg {
    /* the faPlay icon is centered by the point that meets the (triangle hight)/2 .
    this class centers it by its circumcenter .

    consider that the faPlay icon is an equilateral triangle ,
    horizontally centered (left and right white spaces are equal ) 

    and because of these two rules in the parent button :
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;

    the width of the button is equal to two times a triangle side .

    you can then calculate the percentage to offset
    the whole svg icon so that the circumcenter of the triangle
    meets the center of the button .*/

    -webkit-transform: translateX(percentage(sqrt(3) / 24));
    -ms-transform: translateX(percentage(sqrt(3) / 24));
    transform: translateX(percentage(sqrt(3) / 24));
}
```

Comment: Its too much long solution and not exact solution

Comment: can i know why please ? the button containing the triangle icon is a square with a length of 2em btw .

Comment: because this is for loop solution, values changes every time and too many mathematics rules are applied in that and final result may be in case in points, so sometimes it cant be best solution !!